# why cpp string assign byte by byte failed?

Tags: c++, string, memory

I have a program that need copy char from one string to another, but after copy the string still empty, and there have no warnings or errors. the similiar code as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s, res;
    s = "hello world";
    int j = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        res[j++] = s[i];
    }
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `res` is an empty `std::string`. `res[j++]` with any value of `j` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @JeJo it is the simple code, the origin logic not like this.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius but when i declare res and then res.capacity() output 15.

Comment: @douyu Capacity doesn't matter. You can index it up to `res.size ()`. Otherwise - it is undefined behavior. Technically, my initial statement was not _entirely_ correct, due to the `std::string` having the ability of being index at `size ()` (`0` in your case). But, trying to write to that memory is undefined behavior, nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't resize the string `res`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s, res;
    s = "hello world";
    res.resize(s.size());
    int j = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        res[j++] = s[i];
    }
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but when i declare res and then res.capacity() output 15.

Comment: @douyu As described in the documentation of [`std::string::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at): "_If pos > size(), the behavior is undefined._"

Comment: @douyu • `res.capacity()` ≠ `res.size()`

Comment: @douyu `.capacity()` only tells you how large the size can get before the vector needs to reallocate memory for itself.

Answer (score 2):

`res` is empty. You assign characters that don't exist in indices that are outside the bounds of the string. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> [behaviour isn't what I expected], and there have no warnings or errors

Welcome to the beginning of your journey to understanding what undefined behaviour is. You cannot trust that warnings and errors will always catch your mistakes in C++.

For what it's worth, my compiler does detect this when I enable standard library debug mode and address sanitiser. Don't neglect your debugging tools.